# Can assignment operator be used in if statements. As if statements are used Boolean expression

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators, assignment-operator

I was expecting an error in `if(b=5)`, as the assignment operator is used in if statement.

```
Code: 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
        
    int a=10, b=10; 
    if(b=5)
        a--; 
    printf("%d, %d", a, b--);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all pick *one* language. C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Secondly what is your "doubt"? What is your question? Thirdly, unless the source is trusted, don't just use code straight off from anywhere. Beware of [the cargo cult programming trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your question.

Comment: What error were you expecting? And why?

Comment: b = 5 is actually an expression and all expressions give a true value.
There is no error but the compiler will give the following warning:
C6282: Incorrect operator: assignment of constant in Boolean context. Consider using '==' instead

Comment: It is valid C to make an assignment inside of an `if` condition. The assignment evaluates to the assigned value. Everything else than an assigned value of `0` evaluates to a `true` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expected it to raise an error because it seems a typo in the attempt to use the comparison operator `==`, usually used in if-statements like this

```
if ( b == 5 )
```

The expression in the if-statement

```
if ( b = 5 )
```

is actually evaluated like every expression in C. In this case its evaluation is the value of the assignment `5`, and since it is not zero it is equivalent to `true` in a boolean expression.

It is probably a subtle typo, so that the author probably performed a comparison instead of that assigment. Anyways it doesn't raise an error because **it is valid C**.

Fortunately, in many compilers a **warning** is raised. Make sure to enable all warnings in your compiler options, and to never ignore them. In this way you will avoid these subtle traps in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the if statement there is a valid assignment. The result of such operation is the assigned value (5) which is valid inside an if statement and evaluates to true.

Actually, any number other than 0 will be interpreted as true.

Maybe you already know, but you are not making a comparison there. The comparison operation is `==`.